# How to bind a TextBlock to a dictionary entry where the key is given by binding?

Tags: wpf, dictionary, binding

Suppose I have a `Dictionary<string, string>` and a `ComboBox` where the items are populated from a collections that holds the keys to that dictionary.
How can I bind a `TextBlock` to the value of the selected key?

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyKeyCollection}"/>

<TextBox Text={Binding //What do I put here? }/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you bind the data inside the combo box -

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}">

        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"
                               Margin="5"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"
                               Margin="5"/>

                </StackPanel>                                

            </DataTemplate>

        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ComboBox>
```

Style it as you wish in the DataTemplate

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you have to be sure that your ViewModel Holds both, KeyCollection and the dictionary. Here my interpretation:

Suppose you have this ViewModel:

```
public class DictVm
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> MainDictionary { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> MyKeyCollection{ get; set; }
        public string SelectedKey{ get; set; }

        private string _selectedDictValue;
        public string SelectedDictValue {
        get {

            if (MainDictionary.TryGetValue(SelectedKey, _selectedDictValue))
                return _selectedDictValue;
            return string.Empty;
        }
        set { _selectedDictValue = value; } }
    }
```

Here is your MainWindow contructor:

```
   private DictVm vm;
   public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        vm = new DictVm();
        DataContext = vm;
    }
```

Here how i would modify the xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyCombo" ItemsSource="{Binding MyKeyCollection}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedKey}"/>

<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedDictValue}"/>
```